# In what order will Oracle use synonym, view, and table objects?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Let's say that my database has the following objects:

- A **table** on schema "B" named "mlb_players"
- A **view** on schema "C" named "mlb_players" that is a SELECT against a table on server "DB2"
- A **synonym** on schema "D" named "mlb_players" that points to a table on server "DB3"

All of these objects are granted to my schema "RedSoxRule"

If I execute this query, from where would the data be retrieved?

```
SELECT *
FROM mlb_players
```

In other words, if a given name (in this case "mlb_players") is applicable to different object types, and the GRANTS are equal, in what order will Oracle find the requested object?

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28343488/Table-and-view-with-same-name.html

Comment: @RobertKock - the whole and entire purpose of StackOverflow is to save developers from visiting **that site** and its pernicious paywall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oracle has a nice long explanation of this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561).

Basically, when resolving a name, it looks:

1. For objects in your schema with that name
2. For public synonyms with that name
3. If the name has multiple parts (e.g. `C.mlb_players`, it checks to see if the first part is a qualifying schema that you have access to.

In your example, Oracle won't find any of them. They're all in different schemas from your `RedSoxRule` schema, none of them are public synonyms, and you didn't qualify `mlb_players` with a schema name.

It doesn't actually matter what the type of the object is (table, view, synonym, package, etc) - they're all treated the same.

Answer (score 2):

> If I execute this query, from where would the data be retrieved

Nowhere. REDSOXRULE has no object called `mlb_players` so the query would fail with `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

You would need to prefix the table name with the schema you're prefixing, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM d.mlb_players;
```

Let's suppose you have a variation on your posted structure.

1. REDSOXRULE has a view `mlb_players` for `a.mlb_players`. The query `select * from mlb_players` would select from this view, i.e from `a.mlb_players`.
2. Instead of a view REDSOXRULE has a private synonym `mlb_players` for `b.mlb_players`.  The query `select * from mlb_players` would select from this synonym, i.e from `b.mlb_players`. Note that you can't have a private synonym with the same name as a table or view in your schema.
3. Instead of a private synonym the database has a public synonym `mlb_players` for `d.mlb_players`.  The query `select * from mlb_players` would select from this publicsynonym, i.e from `d.mlb_players`.

That is, Oracle looks first for objects owned by the schema (tables, views, private synonyms, etc). Then it looks at public synonyms. Then it looks for objects in other schemas